# Formula to display a result only if the formula date returned is less than a Date listed in another cell

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a formula where if the calculation date of the formula exceeds the given month it will display `N/A`.

I.e. I have the last workday as the 29/7/16 from

```
=WORKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1),-1)
```

in B2 which is referencing A2 and I'm running a column with `=WORKDAY(A2, 1)` consecutively down a column to only return the workdays of that month as calculated by the above forumla.

The issue I've run into is if the date down that column results in a day that is greater than the last workday of that month I want, I would like it to not display a result.

The idea being this would be a template which would be used for the next month in the year and would only display days of the relevant month and return `N/A` if it's not in July for instance.

The forumla I've tried is

```
IF(WORKDAY(A68, 1) < DATEVALUE(B2),"N/A", "(WORKDAY(A68, 1)")
```

I can't seem to get anything to work, am I missing something? I'm a formula noob, still trying to learn :)

P.S. I have managed to get it doing what I want by creating a hidden column that does the networkdays and then using an IF statement such as

```
=IF(A68 < C$2,WORKDAY(A65, 1),"NA")
```

but I would like to make it one formula if possible.

Comment: You can always put that formula of yours in the hidden column right into your first one. Maybe post that code as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cell B2 is holding a Date (`WORKDAY` returns a date), not text. So the `DATEVALUE` function returns an error when you apply it to that cell, as expected.

Also, you should not put the "else" portion of the if inside quotes if you want to see the result of the function.

So this should work fine:

```
=IF(WORKDAY(A68, 1) < B2,"N/A", WORKDAY(A68, 1))
```